# Node.js Globalize es6 modules to act like ImportScripts

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, node-modules, ecmascript-5

The question is simple, how do we make es6 modules act like the ImportScript function used on the web browser.

### Explanation

The main reason is to soften the blow for developers as they change their code from es5 syntax to es6 so that the transition does not blow up your code the moment you make the change and find out there are a thousand errors due to missing inclusions. It also give's people the option to stay as is indefinitely if you don't want to make the full change at all.

### Desired output

ImportScript(A file path/'s);  can be applied globally(implicitly) across subsequently required code and vise-verse inside a main file to avoid explicit inclusion in all files.

### ES6 Inclusion

This still does not ignore the fact that all your libraries will depend on modules format as well. So it is inevitable that we will still have to include the export statement in every file we need to require. However, this should not limit us to the ability to have a main file that interconnects them all without having to explicitly add includes to every file whenever you need a certain functionality.

### DISCLAIMER'S

(Numbered):

1. (Security) I understand there are many reasons that modules exist and going around them is not advisable for security reasons/load times. However I am not sure about the risk (if any) of even using a method like "eval()" to include such scripts if you are only doing it once at the start of an applications life and to a constant value that does not accept external input. The theory is that if an external entity is able to change the initial state of your program as is launched then your system has already been compromised. So as it is I think the whole argument around Globalization vs modules boils down to the project being done(security/speed needed) and preference/risk.
2. (Not for everyone) This is a utility I am not implying that everyone uses this
3. (Already published works) I have searched a lot for this functionality but I am not infallible to err. So If a simple usage of this has already been done that follows this specification(or simpler), I'd love to know how/where I can attain such code. Then I will promptly mark that as the answer or just remove this thread entirely

### Example Code

### ES5 Way

```
const fs = require('fs'); 
let path = require('path'); 
    /* only accepts the scripts with global variables and functions and 
       does not work with classes unless declared as a var.
    */ 

    function include(f) { 
        eval.apply(global, [fs.readFileSync(f).toString()]) 
    }
```

Main file Concept example:

```
        ImportScript("filePath1");loaded first 
        ImportScript("filePath2");loaded second
        ImportScript("filePath3");loaded third
        ImportScript("filePath4");loaded fourth
        ImportScript("filePath5");loaded fifth
       ImportScript("someExternalDependency");sixth  
    
        /* where "functionNameFromFile4" is a function defined in 
         file4 , and "variableFromFile2" is a global dynamic 
         variable that may change over the lifetime of the 
         application.
        */

        functionNameFromFile4(variableFromFile2); 

        /* current context has access to previous scripts contexts 
         and those scripts recognize the current global context as 
         well in short: All scripts should be able to access 
         variables and functions from other scripts implicitly 
         through this , even if they are added after the fact
        */
```

Typical exported file example (Covers all methods of export via modules):

```
/*where "varFromFile1" is a dynamic variable created in file1
that may change over the lifetime of the application and "var" is a 
variable of type(varFromFile4) being concatenated/added together 
with "varFromFile4".
*/

functionNameFromFile4(var){
    return var+varFromFile1;
}

//Typical export statement
exportAllHere;

/* 
This is just an example and does not cover all usage cases , just 
an example of the possible functionality
*/
```

### CONCLUSION

So you still need to export the files as required by the es6 standard , however you only need to import them once in a main file to globalize their functionality across all scripts.

Comment: You don't.  ES6 modules are different.  They have different rules, they have different features, etc... They are not the same and cannot be made to be the same as CommonJS modules.  The line in your "conclusion" proposes something completely different that is 100% opposite of modularity where you want to import once and have something globally available.  That has nothing at all to do with `require()` or `import` so with that one ending sentence, you completely confused your entire question.

Comment: Ok that is fine I can restructure my question to be a bit more clear.

Comment: FYI, the opposite of modularity is assigning lots of things to the global scope.  You can do that with explicit assignment of properties to the `global` object, but it is not recommend for all the same reasons that nodejs was invented with a modular system at its core and the same reason that the Javascript language itself is moving to a modular system.  Lots of global things creates a developer mess and a testing mess.

Comment: Nothing stands on its own as independently testable or shareable when you're using globals for lots of things.  Everyone who balks at a little extra typing at the start of a module to bring in the common things you want to use in that module eventually realizes it's no big deal and then it allows you to realize all the benefits of using independently testable and sharable modules.  You could say it's a small price to pay for all the benefits you get.  So, while you can assign things to the global object and make them available everywhere, ***don't do it***.

Comment: maybe read disclaimer 3

Comment: If you want to ask about a transition strategy or a co-exist strategy from CommonJS modules to ESM modules (what point 3 seems to be about), then ask about that and describe a very specific problem you want help with.  Your question seems to describe very different things.  In fact, it seems you've mixed up a whole bunch of different things in the question and somehow blamed it all on `require()` vs. `import` when much of it has nothing to do with that.

Comment: That is a fair point , I will make that change as well , However I do feel people should read disclaimers before making such statements.

Comment: No number of disclaimers makes an unclear question that asks about a bunch of unrelated things into a clear question.   You need to write a clear question if you want the best chance of getting help here.  I've already offered my thoughts (in comments) about making modules globally available without importing or requiring them in each place you want to use them.

Comment: I made the suggested changes :) , if you still see something out of place let me know , I am really trying to get this answered and I don't mean to make anyone confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240234/discussion-between-static660-and-jfriend00).

Comment: OK, now the question is starting to make sense.   Certainly the title is much clearer now.

Comment: Are your modules CommonJS modules or ESM modules as the solution would be different depending upon the type of source module?  Are you exporting the things you want to be global within the modules?

Comment: Sorry about that , I did forget that you were right and that require does not exactly work as I explained but the build I have. I will include the simple snippet in a moment for further clarification. But basically Globalizing code . Javascript being very simple to understand for most programmers is a very high language and should emphasize on simplicity and this question answered I feel would align with that principle. Otherwise probably should use python or ruby or like any other language for backend imo.

Comment: The problem is that I don't expect cjs to last , it will likely depricate in the next 5 years. Also mixing cjs and modules can be very confusing and from now on whenever any of your dependencies update to modules it is just going to break your code. Who knows, maybe modules will get replaced some day but for now as far as I can see I don't see it going anywhere fast.

Comment: Can you show an example of what's inside a file you want to `include()` and what symbols in that file you want to become globally available?  Are you exporting those symbols?

Comment: I have made the snippet available now

Comment: Thank you for your time and criticism :)  put me right

Comment: "*act like the include function used on the web browser.*" - uh, there is no `include` function on web browsers? And the `include` implementation you've shown isn't even for browsers, it rather looks like your own home-grown "module" system which is neither CommonJS nor ES6 modules. Too be honest, I still have absolutely no idea what you are asking about. You explain your situation and make a number of (dubious) claims in something like an essay, but there is not a single question in your post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not personally a fan of globalizing all the exports from a module, but here's a little snippet that shows you how one ESM module's exports can be all assigned to the global object:

Suppose you had a simple module called `operators.js`:

```
export function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

export function subtract(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}
```

You can import that module and then assign all of its exported properties to the global object with this:

```
import * as m from "./operators.js"

for (const [prop, value] of Object.entries(m)) {
    global[prop] = value;
}

// can now access the exports globally
add(1, 2);
```

---

FYI, I think the syntax:

```
include("filePath1")
```

is going to be tough in ESM modules because dynamic imports in an ESM module using `import` (which is presumably what you would have to use to implement the `include()` function you show) are asynchronous (they return a promise), not synchronous like `require()`.

---

I wonder if a bundler or a transpiler would be an option?

There is experimental work in nodejs related to custom loaders here: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#hooks.

---

If you can handle your `include()` function returning a promise, here's how you put the above code into that function:

```
async function include(moduleName) {
    const m = await import(moduleName);
    for (const [prop, value] of Object.entries(m)) {
        global[prop] = value;
    }
    return m;
}
```

Comment: If it is simple to implement and it covers easily globalizing things then it works for me . If all you need to do is include a library can call it or something similar. The purpose of this is to give programmers the ability to write code to later (once produced) change to ES6 or keep depending on the situation/desire. it is to make coding less painful as sometimes you just wat to delete a function without it screwing the export/import statement at the same time as being easy to implement. I think I saw an exportAll statement.

Comment: @static660 - I don't know if you saw the rest of my answer that I added recently.  You can't put the code I have in the second code block into a function and then call it because you can't do this type of `import` from within a function.  It can only be done at the top level in a module.  Doing `import` from within a function has to be done as a function call `import("module")` and becomes a `dynamic` import which is not synchronous and returns a promise.

Comment: That is fine I can always wrap it in an async wrapper then init the program once it loads the promises .

Comment: @static660 - OK, I put that code into an `include()` function that returns a promise (added to my  answer).  You will have to manage how you "wait" for the promise to resolve.